# How to return Bitcoins to sender through Bitcoin API?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, json-rpc, raw-data, api

I want to get information about the creator of a given transaction through Bitcoin API. More specifically, any or all addresses they sent their Bitcoins from, so I can return some of the money back. Is it possible to do using just the JSON RPC, or do I have to rely on external sources (such as the Block Explorer)?

Comment: I would strongly urge you not to do this. For one thing, if the money was sent to you from a typical web-based wallet or exchange, the money will *not* go back to the sender.

Comment: The only correct way to do a refund, is to ask the sender to provide a refund address. You may be able to observe some of the addresses some of the input coins were previously sent to, but there is no guarantee that the sender expects/accepts refunds to those. Typical standalone Bitcoin clients do, but there are far from the only players on the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the address is in your wallet, gettransaction includes the input addresses:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

If this is done by an agent where the addresses might not be in the wallet, v0.7 getrawtransaction gives you [access to those transactions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=89725.msg990497#msg990497).

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions

There are other tools that you can use to build this capability as well.

- libBitcoin
- Armory (see [Extras](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/tree/master/extras))
- Bitcoin ABE